# How can I find my warning place in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, warnings

I have some warning in my code, but I can't found where those happened. How can I find the place of warning?

This is my warning in console

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <table> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
    at table
    at http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:1131:66
    at Table (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:97587:79)
    at div
    at http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:1131:66
    at Paper (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:84171:79)
    at http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:1131:66
    at TableContainer (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:95943:79)
    at InnerThemeProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:108555:67)
    at ThemeProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:107463:5)
    at ThemeProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:108575:5)
    at BasicTable (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:132450:20)
    at p
    at http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:1131:66
    at Typography (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:101212:84)
    at div
    at http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:1131:66
    at Box (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:110064:69)
    at div
    at TabPanel (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:132631:24)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at SwipeableViews (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:211683:34)
    at div
    at http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:1131:66
    at Box (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:110064:69)
    at InnerThemeProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:108555:67)
    at ThemeProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:107463:5)
    at ThemeProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:108575:5)
    at ProductMetaReview (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:132677:19)
    at div
    at div
    at ProductSingleDetails (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:132920:20)
    at div
    at Container (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:134071:23)
    at ProductPage (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:137283:24)
    at main
    at div
    at Layout (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/products/%5BproductSlug%5D/%5Bslug%5D.js?ts=1680587655234:131448:23)
    at UIProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:12728:72)
    at CartProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:12113:99)
    at ManagedUIContext (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:12912:23)
    at Hydrate (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:67267:23)
    at QueryClientProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:67342:21)
    at PresenceChild (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:18809:23)
    at AnimatePresence (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:18970:23)
    at CustomApp (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:13178:25)
    at I18nextProvider (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1680587655234:54335:19)
    at AppWithTranslation
    at ErrorBoundary (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1680587655234:725:47)
    at ReactDevOverlay (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1680587655234:841:23)
    at Container (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1680587655234:8855:5)
    at AppContainer (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1680587655234:9351:24)
    at Root (http://dev.etma.site/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1680587655234:9490:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a search for these strings together to find the place in your codebase where a warning about the use of "table" and "p" together first appeared. This can assist you in identifying the precise lines of code that are the problem.

Another method is to isolate the issue by leaving certain code snippets uncommented and testing to see if the warning disappears. This can assist you in identifying the troublesome code and resolving the issue.

Comment: I searched, but not found anything

Answer (score 1):

Check all your components under `products` folder which contains `<table>` element.

Are you using `<table>` inside `<p>`?

Comment: No I checked all of them and just in one component I used table that it was just wrapped by Theme Provider

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue? What theme provider you're using?

Comment: Not yet. I use MUI theme provider